# FastAPI/Starlette get client IP in path operation function

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I am trying to access the client IP inside FastAPI path operation function like in the documentation here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_root(item_id: str, request: Request):
    client_host = request.client.host
    return {"client_host": client_host, "item_id": item_id}
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'host'
```

It seems that the `request.client` returns `None`. Starlette documentation says `request.client` should be a named two-tuple. https://www.starlette.io/requests/

Any suggestions how to get access to the IP?

Comment: How are you running your application? Works as expected with FastAPI and uvicorn directly.

Comment: @MatsLindh I''ve followed this tutorial to setup the application to run inside Azure function app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/

Comment: Then it kind of sounds like an issue with how Azure functions integrate with the ASGI protocol, and not a FastAPI/Starlette issue directly. Have you seen https://demiliani.com/2022/07/11/azure-functions-getting-the-client-ip-address/ ? It might only be available through the `X–Forwarded-For` header. I'd inspect the whole `request` object to see what the Azure functions host includes.

Comment: Thank you! `X-Forwarded-For` header did the trick after the app was deployed to Azure.